# Expand all classes name in Visual Studio UML diagram

Tags: visual-studio-2013, class-diagram

I have a visual studio project with more than 100 classes.  Therefore, when I generate the Class diagram in Visual Studio, the names of these classes are collapsed as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

How can I expand the names of all the classes? I need to see only the complete names, ***not the whole structure of the class***.

Answer (score 2):

Select all classes (Ctrl + A),  Right Click --> Expand ;)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on class and click adjust shapes width
[image]